# Why does datetime.datetime return different results than pd.to_datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am wondering why `datetime.datetime.timestamp` return different results than `pd.to_datetime.timestamp`

Here is an example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

now = datetime.now()
print(now.timestamp())
print(pd.to_datetime(now).timestamp())

# 1572490362.553197
# 1572472362.553197
```

Comment: I think pandas timestamp is based on `local time zone` and datetime timestamp is based on `UTC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bharath M is correct:

```
import datetime 
import pandas as pd

now = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
print(now.timestamp())
print(pd.to_datetime(now, utc=True).timestamp())

# 1572493959.718966
# 1572493959.718966
```